# ASP / Javascript Open Source Web Image Resizer

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, image-processing

Does anyone know of a open source library that would allow me to do something similar to the functionality found on this site: http://webresizer.com/resizer?  I would hate to create one from scratch if one already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one .. after I saw your question I remembered that I needed something like that too, just found this and installed.It worked.

http://webcropimage.codeplex.com/releases/view/47555

you can checkout samples,

[sample1](http://samples.cemsisman.com/webcropimage/Sample1.aspx)

[sample2](http://samples.cemsisman.com/webcropimage/Ratiosample.aspx)

[sample3](http://samples.cemsisman.com/webcropimage/Fixedsize.aspx)

[sample4](http://samples.cemsisman.com/webcropimage/Scaled.aspx)

good luck..

Answer (score 1):

I assume using http://imagemagick.codeplex.com/ could easily be used on the backend to do the resizing and other image 'magick' as required.